# what is the date format from stash api?

Tags: bitbucket-server

In the below json response, what is the date format for createdDate and updatedDate? I am not sure how to work in reverse to find what format the api is using for date. I couldn't find this any where in the documentation.

```
{
"size": 1,
"limit": 25,
"isLastPage": true,
"values": [
    {
        "id": 101,
        "version": 1,
        "title": "Talking Nerdy",
        "description": "It’s a kludge, but put the tuple from the database in the cache.",
        "state": "OPEN",
        "open": true,
        "closed": false,
        "createdDate": 1359075920,
        "updatedDate": 1359085920,
        "fromRef": {
            "id": "refs/heads/feature-ABC-123",
            "repository": {
                "slug": "my-repo",
                "name": null,
                "project": {
                    "key": "PRJ"
                }
            }
        },
        "toRef": {
            "id": "refs/heads/master",
            "repository": {
                "slug": "my-repo",
                "name": null,
                "project": {
                    "key": "PRJ"
                }
            }
        },
        "locked": false,
        "author": {
            "user": {
                "name": "tom",
                "emailAddress": "tom@example.com",
                "id": 115026,
                "displayName": "Tom",
                "active": true,
                "slug": "tom",
                "type": "NORMAL"
            },
            "role": "AUTHOR",
            "approved": true
        },
        "reviewers": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "jcitizen",
                    "emailAddress": "jane@example.com",
                    "id": 101,
                    "displayName": "Jane Citizen",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "jcitizen",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "REVIEWER",
                "approved": true
            }
        ],
        "participants": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "dick",
                    "emailAddress": "dick@example.com",
                    "id": 3083181,
                    "displayName": "Dick",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "dick",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                "approved": false
            },
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "harry",
                    "emailAddress": "harry@example.com",
                    "id": 99049120,
                    "displayName": "Harry",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "harry",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                "approved": true
            }
        ],
        "link": {
            "url": "http://link/to/pullrequest",
            "rel": "self"
        },
        "links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "http://link/to/pullrequest"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"start": 0
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a UNIX timestamp.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 2):

Just making a note that in my case, it is a UNIX timestamp, but I have to remove three trailing zeroes. E.g. the data looks like this:

```
"createdDate":1555621993000
```

If interpreted as a UNIX timestamp, that would be 09/12/51265 @ 4:16am (UTC).

By removing the three trailing zeroes I get 1555621993, which is the correct time 04/18/2019 @ 9:13pm (UTC)

Your mileage may vary but that was a key discovery for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The timestamps I'm seeing come back from the APi are the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch, `1/1/1970 00:00:00.000`. In .NET, convert to a `DateTime` like so:

```cs
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(timestamp)
```

PowerShell:

```
[DateTime]::New(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds($timestamp)
```